# Running multiple Task

Tags: .net

I'm trying to execute multiple Tasks at the same time

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true) {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Write("Enter number of cart: ");
            var numOfCarts = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter number of items: ");
            var numOfItems = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            RunTasks(numOfCarts, numOfItems).Wait();
        }
    }

    public static async Task RunTasks(int numOfCarts, int numOfItems)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < numOfCarts; i++)
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var color = (ConsoleColor) new Random().Next(0, 15);
                for (var q = 0; q < numOfItems; q++) {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                    Console.WriteLine("Cart {0} : {1}", i, q);
                }
            });
    }
```

is this correct implementation? ForegroundColor rarely changes. I would like the console color to be different for each cart.

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix up `Task.Wait()` calls and `async / await`. In your case, it may lead to **deadlock** when main thread waits for `RunTasks` to execute while `RunTasks` waits for main thread to start continuation.

In your case, you could simply use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write("Enter number of cart: ");
        var numOfCarts = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter number of items: ");
        var numOfItems = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        RunTasks(numOfCarts, numOfItems).Wait();
    }
}

public static Task RunTasks(int numOfCarts, int numOfItems)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[numOfCarts];
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfCarts; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var color = (ConsoleColor) new Random().Next(0, 15);
            for (var q = 0; q < numOfItems; q++) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                Console.WriteLine("Cart {0} : {1}", i, q);
            }
        });
    }

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

- `RunTasks` starts up many `Task`s and returns a task which will complete when all subtasks are complete.
- `Main` will start `RunTasks` and block main thread until `RunTasks` finishes.

At the same time, you can make `await Task.WhenAll` in `RunTasks` and then `await RunTasks()` in `Main`, but it doesn't make much sense - your main thread is always busy and will infinitely do one job (which is `RunTasks`).